# Laravel isDirty() & getOriginal() not working with pivot relationship in observer

Tags: laravel

In my project, I want to keep track of updated comments. So if a comment is updated, the old comment is saved in a comment_history table. I am using observer for this. But user can tag other users in a comment. So, I have a many-to-many pivot table comment_user.

I have defined a belongsToMany relationship in my comment model with the user model. So far I can insert it into comment_history when the comment field changes. But I also want to insert into comment_history when the tagged users are changed in a comment. I want the tagged user ids in comma-separated to be inserted in the old_tagged_users fields in comment_history. But isDirty() & getOriginal() doesn't work with pivot relationship.

```
class CommentObserver
{
    public function updated(Comment $comment)
    {
        if($comment->isDirty('comment') || $comment->taggedUsers()->isDirty() ){
            $history = new CommentHistory();
            $history->old_comment = $comment->getOriginal('comment');

            $history->old_tagged_users = //old tagged user_ids in comma separeted
            
            $comment->history()->save($history);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: not the best way, but think it will work. Add `tagged_users` to the comment table, where user_ids will store just for comparing with the new ones

Comment: Yeah. But is there any better way to achieve what I want! Without using observer?

Comment: I am not sure if this will help you, but maybe defining your `pivot` as a `custom model` instead of a `raw relationship` will allow you to use `isDirty` and `getOriginal`. Read [this part of the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) and try to apply it and see if it works.

Comment: I am already using custom pivot model. It doesn't work.